# How to mirror two group plot compositions

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggdist

I already have the following plot, which I am already satisfied by

```
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggdist)

 
dat1 <- as.data.frame(c(175.070, 279.760, 310.120, 454.370, 356.190, 398.720, 394.790, 427.940, 450.090, 452.240, 344.630, 374.450, 401.810,
          366.250, 455.150, 455.150, 284.820, 325.640, 437.840, 455.150, 455.150, 454.900, 433.970, 346.830, 455.050, 455.150,
          448.740, 455.150, 455.000, 455.150, 243.920, 295.660, 282.430, 305.190, 368.580, 348.440, 437.100, 453.180, 454.100,
          44.464, 420.280, 455.150, 427.250, 101.490, 454.100, 454.810, 323.690, 454.410, 235.160, 294.870, 455.150, 330.460,
          289.610, 236.310, 454.810, 299.020,  29.289,  39.988, 348.340, 455.150, 439.540, 409.910, 440.310, 433.090, 455.150,
          198.890, 454.100, 346.370, 261.780, 280.760, 427.180, 455.150, 233.740, 334.040, 452.240, 411.890, 378.310, 354.410,
          347.670, 439.970))
colnames(dat1) = "value"


dat1$group <- rep(NA,nrow(dat1))
for (i in 1:nrow(dat1)){
  if (i <= 40){
    dat1[i,]$group <- print('C')
  }else{
    dat1[i,]$group <- print('I')
  }
}

dat1$group <- factor(dat1$group, levels = c('C','I'))

pltt <- rev(wes_palette(n=2, name="Darjeeling1"))

#Model 1

#M1 Loglikelihood
p1 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x=group, y=value, color=group, fill=group)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=pltt, guide = "none") +
  scale_color_manual(values=pltt, guide = "none") +
  stat_halfeye(adjust = .33, width = .6, alpha=0.3, position = position_nudge(x=0.3)) +
  geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.1), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("C", "I")), tip_length = -0.01, y_position = -0.5, 
              map_signif_level=TRUE, test="wilcox.test", color = "black") +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_nudge(x=0.2), width=0.05,outlier.shape = NA, fill=alpha(0.2)) +
  ylim(0,460) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=14,face="bold")) +
  theme_light() +
  ggtitle("Data distribution")
```

[image: Plot 1]

Now I was wondering whether there is a way to invert the order or mirror this composition into something like this.

[image: Plot Mirrored]

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957319/r-by-group-mirrored-histogram-using-ggplot2) and I see there is a way of doing it with density plots, but I was wondering if anyone knows a way of doing it in composites of plots like mine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can mirror the density plot, you can do it. You have to fiddle with your x offsets, which you hard-coded anywhere. You should be able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option could be by using each `geom` with a `subset` of your group. To get the `stat_halfeye` on the right side you could use the argument `side` for both. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggdist)

ggplot() +
  stat_halfeye(data = subset(dat1, group == "C"),
               aes(x=group, y=value, color=group, fill=group), 
               adjust = .33, width = .6, alpha=0.3, position = position_nudge(x=-0.3), side = "left") +
  geom_jitter(data = subset(dat1, group == "C"),
              aes(x=group, y=value, color=group, fill=group),
              shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.1), alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = subset(dat1, group == "C"),
               aes(x=group, y=value, color=group, fill=group), 
               position = position_nudge(x=-0.2), width=0.05,outlier.shape = NA, fill=alpha(0.2)) +
  stat_halfeye(data = subset(dat1, group == "I"),
               aes(x=group, y=value, color=group, fill=group), 
               adjust = .33, width = .6, alpha=0.3, position = position_nudge(x=0.3), side = "right") +
  geom_jitter(data = subset(dat1, group == "I"),
              aes(x=group, y=value, color=group, fill=group),
              shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.1), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(data = subset(dat1, group == "I"),
               aes(x=group, y=value, color=group, fill=group), 
               position = position_nudge(x=0.2), width=0.05,outlier.shape = NA, fill=alpha(0.2)) +
  geom_signif(data = dat1,
              aes(x=group, y=value, color=group, fill=group),
              comparisons = list(c("C", "I")), tip_length = -0.01, y_position = -0.5, 
              map_signif_level=TRUE, test="wilcox.test", color = "black") +
  ylim(0,460) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=14,face="bold")) +
  theme_light() +
  ggtitle("Data distribution")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is brilliant! I didn't know there was a side parameter. Great stuff, thanks!